# Using dbml with stored procedures in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I had created a project in MVC using Webforms.I need to include dbml with stored procedures in MVC.I am new to MVC and I know that I need to create the dbml and call those in model.

I do not know how to implement it.Please send me a sample project in MVC having stored procedures in dbml.

Any url please.

Regards
S.Guhananth

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Answer (score 0):

So, since you mention dbml, we know you use Linq to SQL. It has really nothing to do with MVC, as you can use Linq to SQL with any front end technology. Here is the sample tutorial:

http://dodgenotes.blogspot.ca/2012/02/how-to-create-dbml-and-invoke-stored.html